# word meaning every permutation

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for a complete set of permutations?

I thought the correct word was 'Tautology', but it seems I misunderstood a lecture about propositional logic.

> An example:
>
> The following is a (tautological?) list of minecraft weather:
>
> - clear day
> - clear night
> - rainy day
> - rainy night
> - thundery day
> - thundery night

were it the case that it was day/not-day and clear/not-clear and the list was or'd together I suppose tautological would be the correct word, but as its not, what word fits best?

Comment: In mathematics, this is known as a *symmetric group*. I don't know if this term can be used in non-mathematical discourse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try "exhaustive" list or "comprehensive" list.

Comment: "Complete", too